# npm run The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: angular, npm

Can anyone please help? When I run the command
npm run cypress:open I get the saying.

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
I think it was working before fine but after I upgrade my node it stopped working.

npm run The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

My package.json file

```
  "name": "esb-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ngcc": "ngcc",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:es5": "ng serve --configuration es5",
    "start:prod": "npm run ng-high-memory -- serve --configuration production",
    "prebuild": "npm run updateversion",
    "build": "npm run ng-high-memory -- build --configuration production --aot",
    "test": "npm run ng-high-memory -- test --browsers chrome_headless --watch=false",
    "test-ie11": "ng test --browsers IE --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "test-edge": "ng test --browsers Edge --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "test-chrome": "ng test --browsers chrome_headless --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "test-firefox": "ng test --browsers firefox_headless --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "test-safari": "ng test --browsers Safari --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "test-all": "ng test --browsers firefox_headless,chrome_headless,Edge,IE --code-coverage --watch=false",
    "test:watch": "ng test --browsers Chrome",
    "test:error": "ng test --browsers Chrome --sourcemaps=false --watch=false",
    "test:teamcity": "ng test --reporters teamcity --browsers chrome_headless --watch=false",
    "prod": "npm run ng-high-memory -- test --browsers chrome_headless --watch=false && ng lint --force --format=json ui > lint.json && npm run ng-high-memory -- build --configuration production",
    "lint": "ng lint ui",
    "e2e:help": "ng e2e --help",
    "e2e:driver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e:sandbox": "ng e2e --configuration=sandbox",
    "e2e:local:no-build": "ng e2e --configuration=local-no-build",
    "e2e:local": "ng e2e",
    "sonar": "ng test --browsers chrome_headless --watch=false --code-coverage && ng lint --force --format=json > lint.json",
    "coverage": "ng test --browsers chrome_headless --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "coverage:show": "ng test --browsers chrome_headless --watch=false --code-coverage && http-server -c-1 -o -p 9874 ./coverage",
    "format:fix": "pretty-quick src/**/*",
    "eslint:fix": "eslint src/**/*.ts --fix",
    "lint:fix": "ng lint --fix --quiet ui",
    "format:lint:fix": "npm run format:fix && npm run lint:fix",
    "prestart": "npm run updateversion",
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "updateversion": "node version.js",
    "ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:open-sandbox": "cypress open --env configFile=sandbox",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run",
    "cypress:verify": "cypress verify",
    "cypress:run-sandbox": "cypress run --env configFile=sandbox",
    "cypress:run-firefox-sandbox": "cypress run --browser firefox --env configFile=sandbox",
    "cypress:run-chrome-sandbox": "cypress run --browser chrome --env configFile=sandbox",
    "cypress:teamcity-run-sandbox": "cypress run --env configFile=sandbox --reporter cypress-teamcity-reporter"
  },
  "config": {
    "unsafe-perm": true
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^13.0.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "13.0.2",
    "@asymmetrik/leaflet-d3": "^4.4.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^6.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
    "angular-gridster2": "^12.0.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "1.1.1",
    "backoff-rxjs": "^6.5.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "c3": "^0.7.15",
    "case": "^1.6.2",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "chartjs-adapter-moment": "^1.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "3.2.1",
    "cron-expression-validator": "^1.0.20",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "d3": "~5.9.4",
    "d3-hexbin": "0.2.2",
    "dropzone": "5.2.0",
    "html2canvas": "1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "http-server": "^0.12.1",
    "immutable": "3.8.2",
    "is-in-viewport": "^3.0.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-base64": "1.0.0",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.1",
    "jquery-ui-monthpicker": "^1.0.3",
    "jquery-xml2json": "0.0.8",
    "jsplumbtoolkit": "file:./thirdparty_modules/jsplumbtoolkit-1.18.5.tgz",
    "jsplumbtoolkit-angular": "file:./thirdparty_modules/jsplumbtoolkit-angular-1.18.5.tgz",
    "karma-edge-launcher": "0.4.2",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "1.0.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "md5": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "monaco-editor": "~0.24.0",
    "monaco-languageclient": "^0.13.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.5.0",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^12.0.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postinstall": "^0.4.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "time-ago-pipe": "^1.3.2",
    "tinycolorpicker": "0.9.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "vkbeautify": "0.99.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "13.0.3",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.0.2",
    "@cypress/schematic": "^1.6.0",
    "@types/c3": "^0.7.4",
    "@types/d3-hexbin": "0.2.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasmine-jquery": "^1.5.33",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.33",
    "@types/jqueryui": "1.12.4",
    "@types/jsonpath": "0.2.0",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.2.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/underscore": "1.8.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "current-git-branch": "^1.1.0",
    "cypress": "^9.7.0",
    "cypress-file-upload": "^5.0.8",
    "cypress-teamcity-reporter": "^3.0.0",
    "cypress-xpath": "^1.6.2",
    "del-cli": "^1.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-class-members": "^1.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^1.1.4",
    "fs-extra": "^8.1.0",
    "git-describe": "^4.0.4",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-jquery-matchers": "^2.1.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jasmine-test-container-support": "^0.1.2",
    "jsonpath": "1.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.9",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "karma-jasmine-jquery": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-parallel": "^0.3.1",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "1.0.0",
    "karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter": "0.0.18",
    "karma-teamcity-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "less": "^3.11.1",
    "lint-staged": "^8.2.1",
    "ng-lint-staged": "7.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "protractor-http-client": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.4",
    "typescript-require": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.67.0"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/app/*": [
      "eslint --fix --quiet",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged",
      "pre-push": "npm run test"
    }
  }
}
```

I am on node v16.15.1
npm 8.13.0

Comment: I just installed npm version 8.15.0 and it works out of the box. So it was fixed. Probably relevant information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a solution. It is problem with NPM 8.13.0
Downgrading to npm 8.12.2 works.

Comment: The problem occurs when running an npm-script through an npm-script - e.g. `"run-script":  "npm run install", "install": "npm clean-install"` the command `npm run run-install` fails, but `npm run install` works. Downgrading didn't help for me.

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't imagine that NPM was the problem. 

You can also update to the latest version now for a fix.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution. npm install -g npm@8.12.2 because the problem is npm version 8.13.x

Or

npm install -g npm@'anotherVersion'